# Testing a Spring app using REST controllers in Postman

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, postman

So, my code is this:

BasicApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
public class BasicApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

ControllerHome.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping()
public class ControllerHome {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

LessonController.java

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping
@SessionAttributes({"types", "positions", "lectureList", "published"})
public class ControllerLecture {

    List<Lecture> lectureList= new ArrayList<>();

    @RequestMapping
    public String newLecture() {

        return "newLecture";
    }

    @GetMapping("/newLecture")
    public String showForm(Model model, Lecture lecture) {

        log.info("Filling data to show form.");

        model.addAttribute("lecture", new Lecture ());
        model.addAttribute("types", Lecture.LectureType.values());
        model.addAttribute("positions", Lecturer.LecturerPositions.values());
        model.addAttribute("published", lecture.getPublished());

        return "newLecture";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allLectures")
    public String showLectures() {

        return "allLectures";
    }

    @GetMapping("/resetCounter")
    public String resetCounter(SessionStatus status) {

        lectureList.clear();
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/newLecture";
    }

    @PostMapping("/newLecture")
    public String processForm(@Valid Lecture lecture, Errors errors, Model model) {

        log.info("Processing lecture: " + lecture);

        if(errors.hasErrors()) {

            log.info("Lecture has errors. Ending.");

            return "newLecture";

        } else {

            lectureList.add(lecture);

            model.addAttribute("numberOfLectures", lectureList.size());

            model.addAttribute("lecture", lecture);

            model.addAttribute("published", lecture.getPublished());

            model.addAttribute("lectureList", lectureList);

            log.info("Lecture successfully saved: " + lecture);

            return "output";
        }
    }
}
```

LectureRestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/lecture", produces="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class LectureRestController {

    @Autowired
    LectureRepository lectureRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Predavanje> findAll() {

        return lectureRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Lecture> findOne(@PathVariable Long id) {

        Lecture lecture = lectureRepository.findOne(id);

        if(lecture != null) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(lecture, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(consumes="application/json")
    public Lecture save(@RequestBody Lecture lecture) {

        return lectureRepository.save(lecture);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Predavanje update(@RequestBody Lecture lecture) {

        lectureRepository.update(lecture);

        return lecture;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete (@PathVariable Long id) {

        lectureRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

LectureRepository.java (interface)

```
import ... .Lecture;

public interface LectureRepository {

    Iterable<Lecture> findAll();

    Lecture findOne(Long id);

    Lecture save(Lecture lecture);

    Lecture update(Lecture lecture);

    void delete(Long id);
}
```

HibernateLectureRepository.java

```
@Primary
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateLectureRepository implements LectureRepository {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateLectureRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Lecture> findAll() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT p FROM Lecture p", Lecture.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Lecture findOne(Long id) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().find(Lecture.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Lecture save(Lecture lecture) {

        lecture.setEntryDate(new Date());
        Serializable id = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(lecture);
        lecture.setId((Long)id);

        return lecture;
    }

    @Override
    public Lecture update(Lecture lecture) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(lecture);

        return lecture;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {

        Lecture lecture = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().find(Lecture.class, id);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(lecture);
    }

}
```

I have a problem when testing this app with the Postman tool. I know that after I start the app in Spring Tool Suite, I go to the site (localhost:8080) and enter the data there (basic lecture data: name, short content, lecturer...), but when I type the URL in the Postman eg. http://localhost:8080/lecture/1, it prints out nothing as a result, and I don't know why.

The templates that I use are: index.html (homepage), login.html (login page), output.html (page which displays data of the before entered lecture), newLecture.html (a form for entering lectures) and allLectures.html (page which displays the output of all the created lectures). I don't have any templates named "lecture", like referred to in the LectureRestController.java class, is that the problem? Because if it is, I don't know how to create one which will fill itself with data about the lectures.

Update:

This is Postman's response when typing in http://localhost:8080/lecture
[postman1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61O32.jpg)
This is Postman's response when typing in http://localhost:8080/lecture/1
[postman2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WiwO.jpg)

Comment: Could you share the postman response of http://localhost:8080/lecture/1?  as far as I can see your controller should retrieve the lecture with id 1 if exist, otherwise it will return empty (it is maybe your case).

Comment: @EbertToribio I've updated the post and it seems that it is empty, but I don't know why

Comment: I cannot see the Http status of the response.is It 200 ?

Comment: @EbertToribio on the first picture it is, on the second it is 404 Not Found

Comment: the error 404 is because lecture with id=1 do not exist in your database. When lectureRepository.findOne("1") return null you are sending HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND. Maybe you need to find out why that lecture id is not registered in your database

Comment: @EbertToribio do you have any idea why is it nor registered? because the lectures show upon calling the "allLectures.html"

Comment: In what moment you call POST /lecture ? Are you saving it in database?

Comment: nwm, I just noticed in the console that the lecture is getting saved with the `ID = null` and `entryDate = null` also, so I will have to fix that.. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it, the problem was that I wasn't actually calling the method `.save()` in the `LessonController.java` class, specifically in the `processForm` method, in the else block. I've created an `@Autowired` instance of the class `HibernateLectureRepository.java`, and then at the above mentioned spot, I've inserted the instance and called the `.save()` method.

Thank you @EbertToribio for the help provided in the comments.

Comment: can’t, my rep is too low :/